# How to extract part of project based on GNU Build System?

Tags: build, autotools, configure

When I move some subdirectory away from project managed by "./configure" and all that things, it tries to get to some "../../configure.ac" and other things and is not easily buildable.

How to extract part of such project and make it independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to deal with this, create a separate auto-tools build process or do away with the auto-tools and hand code or make a new `Makefile`.

```
myprojectfoo
   |
   +-- src
   |
   +-- man
   |
   +-- messages
   |
   +-- lib
   |
   +-- include
   |
   +-- others
```

Have a look at the illustration above, for a fictitious project called `myprojectfoo` and is using auto-tools to build a binary called `foo`. The top-level directory i.e. `myprojectfoo` will have **configure.ac**, **Makefile.am** and **Makefile.in**, in the subdirectories there would be at least **Makefile.am** and **Makefile.in**. The auto-tools will create and execute the make commands to build the project.

Now, from what I'm understanding in what you are trying to do:

```
myprojectfoo
   |   \ /
   +-- sXc
   |   / \
   +-- man
   |
   +-- messages
   |
   +-- lib
   |     \ /
   +-- incXude
   |     / \
   +-- others
```

You want to take out the `src` subdirectory and it's `include's` also. Then in that case, it would be easier to create a separate Makefile (***read*** - *no auto-tools*) build.. in that case, it would be easier.

The best way I can think of it is, you will have to make that decision ultimately, ***how big is the subset of the project's sources you want to extract***, once you go ahead with that, remove all references to **Makefile.am**, **Makefile.in**... and borrow an existing simple Makefile template to build it and invoke it like this

```
make -f MyMakefile
```

**OR**

If you want to build a separate project using that subset using auto-tools:

1. Create a bare-bones `Makefile.am` as shown below.
2. Create a bare-bones `configure.ac` as shown below...
3. Run **autoscan** on the source to pick out the dependencies, add the results of the output file 'configure.scan' to the `configure.ac`
4. Run **automake** (Do this once!)
5. Run **autoconf** then. It may complain about missing files such as INSTALL, COPYING etc
6. Then any subsequent changes to `configure.ac`, run **autoreconf** after that, which will execute *automake*, *autoconf*, and other supporting auto-tools programs.

Taking a sample of the `Makefile.am` for Linux...

```
SUBDIRS = src include
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

Taking a sample of the `configure.ac` for Linux...

```
AC_PREREQ(2.63)

AC_INIT([mysubsetprojectfoo], [0.1a], [foo@bar.baz])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror])
AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION([0.17])
AM_GNU_GETTEXT([external])
AM_CFLAGS=
# Checks for programs.
AC_HEADER_STDC
AC_PROG_CC

AC_ARG_ENABLE([debug],
[  --enable-debug               Turn on debugging],
[case "${enableval}" in
  yes) debug=true ;;
  no)  debug=false ;;
  *) AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-debug]) ;;
esac],[debug=false])
AM_CONDITIONAL([DEBUG], [test x$debug = xtrue])
# Checks for libraries.
AC_CHECK_LIB([mylib], [mylib_function], [:])
if test "$mylib" = :; then
        AC_MSG_ERROR([MyLib is missing.\
                                  This can be downloaded from 'http://www.foo.baz'])
fi
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Checks for header files. 
# FROM running 'autoscan' on the source directory
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([arpa/inet.h fcntl.h libintl.h locale.h netinet/in.h stdlib.h string.h sys/ioctl.h sys/socket.h syslog.h unistd.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_C_INLINE
AC_C_CONST
AC_TYPE_SIGNAL
AC_TYPE_PID_T
AC_TYPE_UID_T
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_FORK
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([atexit inet_ntoa memset regcomp socket strdup strerror])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile include/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The commands for the auto-tools, is top of my head and I may have missed something..feel free to point out by placing a comment on this at the bottom of this post and it will be amended accordingly.

Comment: Too complex... I just ended up copying the whole project and removing parts from "./configure" script which complained about missing things.

I wanted to extract little supplementary program from big thing. It also had extra unneeded dependencies.

Comment: I thought there may be a thing that analyse makefiles (So big because of autotools) and find subset of source files that are used to build the given target.

Comment: Rather than running automake and autoconf directly (and forgetting to run aclocal, autoheader, libtoolize, etc.), its easier to just run autoreconf.  That will invoke all of the required autotools in the correct order.

Comment: /* Looks like I need a lot more knowledge about autotools to make non-trivial changes to such projects */  In my brain "autotools" and "overcomplexification" is on the one shelf.